# None of the configured nodes are available: []

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, when I try to create a index and type I got this exception.
"None of the configured nodes are available: []"
The following are the code which I use to create "preparIndex".

```
public class Test {
    static {
        CLIENT = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 13101));
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        try {
            IndexResponse response = CLIENT
                                        .prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
                                        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                                            .startObject()
                                            .field("user", "kimchy")
                                            .field("postDate", new Date())
                                            .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                                            .endObject())
                                        .execute()
                                        .actionGet();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }   
    }
}
```

Can any one help me.
Thank you.

Comment: What's the status of your cluster?  Are the nodes running okay?

Comment: Wild quess: Port number should be 9300 (not 13101). 

As @OllyCruickshank suggested, be sure that ES is running on localhost on the default port.

Comment: @OllyCruickshank I am facing a similar problem connecting to elasticsearch single node cluster version 1.7. I am using the java client library version 1.7 and my cluster state is Green and I am also able to connect to the node on port 9300 via telnet. But I keep getting the following error:
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []

Comment: Duplicate of this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277401/org-elasticsearch-client-transport-nonodeavailableexception-none-of-the-configu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally found the reason, that is I used the **default port** **9200** (the correct is **9300** as default).