# org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, docker, elastic4s

I am running `ElasticSearch` on `Docker` which is available locally as

```
$ curl http://192.168.99.100:9200/?pretty
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Collector",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.4",
    "build_hash" : "c88f77ffc81301dfa9dfd81ca2232f09588bd512",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-02-19T13:05:36Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.3"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I am using [Elastic4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s), for connecting to `ElasticSearch`, I tried following approach, but all of them gave me error as

```
val client = ElasticClient.remote(host = "192.168.99.100", port = 9200)
```

and

```
val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build()
  val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://192.168.99.100:9200")
  val client = ElasticClient.remote(uri)
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:305)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:200)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:340)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IndexDsl.scala:23)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IndexDsl.scala:23)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.Executable$class.injectFuture(Executable.scala:21)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$.injectFuture(IndexDsl.scala:20)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$.apply(IndexDsl.scala:23)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$.apply(IndexDsl.scala:20)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticClient.execute(ElasticClient.scala:28)
    at com.enterpriseconnector.persistence.Elastic$.insert(Elastic.scala:17)
    at com.enterpriseconnector.persistence.Test$$anonfun$1.apply(Elastic.scala:27)
    at com.enterpriseconnector.persistence.Test$$anonfun$1.apply(Elastic.scala:24)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:166)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.enterpriseconnector.persistence.Test$.delayedEndpoint$com$enterpriseconnector$persistence$Test$1(Elastic.scala:24)
    at com.enterpriseconnector.persistence.Test$delayedInit$body.apply(Elastic.scala:23)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.enterpriseconnector.persistence.Test$.main(Elastic.scala:23)
    at com.enterpriseconnector.persistence.Test.main(Elastic.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

My complete code is

```
import java.util.Calendar

import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.{ElasticsearchClientUri, ElasticClient}
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl._
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.source.StringDocumentSource
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings

object Elastic {
  println("Creating Elastic Connection")
  val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build()
  val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://192.168.99.100:9200")
  val client = ElasticClient.remote(uri)

  def insert(monitorJson: String) = {
    client execute {
      index into "test" -> "elastic4s" doc StringDocumentSource(monitorJson)
    }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  for (_ <- 1 to 100) yield {
    val json: String = s"{time: ${Calendar.getInstance().getTime()}}"
    println(s"inserting ${json}")
    Elastic.insert(json)
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you running the elastic4s code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

9200 is the port for connecting via HTTP, which is why it works from your browser. If you check you the top of your stack trace, you can see in your case that you're connecting via the Transport client (i.e. TCP) so you need to use the port 9300 instead. Try this:

```
val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://192.168.99.100:9300")
val client = ElasticClient.remote(uri)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure client version is same as ElasticSearch server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding settigs with HTTP enabled

Just set host:

```
val host = "YOUR HOST NAME"
```

and then:

```
val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
    .put("http.enabled", true).put("cluster.name", "CLUSTER-NAME").build()
val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri(s"${host}:9200")
val esClient = ElasticClient
    .remote(settings, uri)
```

It should work with port 9200 now